# How can I add Zurb Foundation as a library?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to add **Zurb Foundation** framework to my theme library file. However, when I add the following code to my library, I'm not getting any result.

I would be grateful to hear what is the problem with the code and what is the right way to load a library?

This is my theme folder structure (Zurb Foundation folder location):

```
|-Theme Name
|  |-includes
|  |  |-foundation
|  |  |  |-css
|  |  |  |-js
```

Library file:

```
foundation:
  version: 6.x
  css:
    includes/foundation/css/app.css: {}
    includes/foundation/css/foundation.css: {}
    includes/foundation/css/foundation.min.css: {}
  js:
    includes/foundation/js/app.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/foundation.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/foundation.min.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/jquery.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/what-input.js: {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created the library, alright, but you need to call the library.

In **[theme_name].info.yml** add the following:

```
libraries:
  - '[theme_name]/foundation'
```

Also you need to modify your **[theme_name].libraries.yml** file and add `dependencies:`

```
foundation:
  version: 6.x
  css:
    base:
      includes/foundation/css/app.css: {}
      includes/foundation/css/foundation.css: {}
      includes/foundation/css/foundation.min.css: {}
  js:
    includes/foundation/js/app.js: {}
    includes/foundation‌​/js/jquery.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/foundation.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/foundation.min.js: {}
    includes/foundation/js/what-input.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
```

As per [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out - I appreciate it greatly! But with this method the css files seem not be loaded.

Comment: Did you flush cache?

Comment: Yes, Even for several time.

Comment: go to performance and uncheckmark aggregate CSS and JS boxes, then view page source with your browser and see what is getting loaded.

Comment: I have done that steps but Nothing has changed.

Comment: Go to your home page, then right click with mouse and select **view page source**. See which .css and .js files are loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43545/discussion-between-mojtaba-reyhani-and-no-sssweat).

Comment: Please edit your answer and add `includes/foundation/js/jquery.js: {}` before `includes/foundation/js/foundation.js: {}` because 
this can cause the problems like this: [How can Create an Orbit Slide Show based on zurb foundation?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211387/how-can-create-an-orbit-slide-show-based-on-zurb-foundation)

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani thx, edited.