# How to create an Orbit slide show based on the zurb foundation?

Tags: 8, javascript

I stubbornly tried to create an Orbit slide show based on zurb foundation 6 framework.

I followed all the steps on the instruction page:[Orbit Slide Show](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/orbit.html).

I added everything needed for this type of slide show and included below CSS and Java Script classes in theme library:

- motion-ui.css
- foundation.css
- foundation.js
- jquery.js

The template code I used is here: [Orbit SlideShow Problem](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/46685-orbit-slideshow-problem)

But unfortunately all images display vertically below each other (one image below another) and the <kbd>Previous</kbd> / <kbd>Next</kbd> button does not work properly, see below image:

[image]

I would be happy to hear what the problem is, share your experiences and guide me to know what is the right way to load that slideshow?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in console?

Comment: @Danny Englander: No,I don't see any error message.

Comment: Go to performance and uncheck aggregate js and css. Then go to the page in question and view page source. Check to see if all the .js and .css files that you need are indeed being loaded.

Comment: @ No Sssweat: I have done that steps but Nothing has been changed.

Comment: I have a few other ideas, either your Drupal markup for this does not match what is actually in Foundation's or you have not instantiated the slideshow with something like `var elem = new Foundation.Orbit(element, options);`

Comment: @Danny Englander: Tank you so much, can you give me more help about `var elem = new Foundation.Orbit(element, options);` how can i use this code in my template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many days searching for cause of this problem in throughout of the web resources, forums and reading variety of article, I fond that this issue for this that I don't
keep the Priority of foundation Files Structure in my library, According to the  Zurb Foundation documentation in this page: [Installing JavaScript](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html)

> It's important that you Make sure "Foundation.js" (or
>   Foundation.min.js) files loads after "jQuery.js" (or jquery.min.js).

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, there is a module that provides this with an 8.x branch in development:

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_orbit

As a maintainer of the 7.x branch, it works great.